# Havoc and Cyclops current fox franchise of X-Men

Tags: marvel, x-men, cyclops

At first I was only slightly aware that Cyclops had a brother. I had watched a bunch of the cartoons growing up, read a few of the comics, and Cyclops was one of my favorite characters. I watched all the movies, I own every single X-men movie, I will admit here are always a few inconsistencies in movies, like the age difference between Scott and Xavier, but for the new timeline it made sense.

When they did the new X-men First Class and added Havoc as a character I was slightly confused. At first I believed that Alex was Cyclops brother, so I was slightly worried about the timeline, because that would make Alex 68 currently and we know as we are the X-men community that that is unreal as he is the younger brother of Cyclops/Scott.

I am worried how they will tie that in even though they are saying that Alex is independent of Scott, I was wondering if perhaps they will arrange for Alex to change his role as a cousin or uncle of Scott or even perhaps his father.
In X-men First Class, havoc is in his late teens early twenties that is in 1962, in Wolverine Origins, Scott is portrayed near the very end and he is in his mid-to-late teens,this takes place in 1981. Probably a sophomore or junior in High school. Scott is most-likely 16 in wolverine origins, in 1981 which mean he was born in 1965 which would logically make him the appropriate age he is in the present-themed films of X-men. Havoc is between 17-22 in 1962. Which means he would have been born 1940-1945. Making him 20-25 years older than Scott. Making him too old to be a brother but logically an uncle or father figure. We could assume the two boys age much older than they should be or resist aging into elderly men. In the comics they absorb the energy of the universe and then throw it out of their bodies as weapons, we could safely assume this same energy keeps them youthful.

My true question is wether or not the next X-men movie will explain this at all, or if they will make some shorts about it, or even, add additional movies that relate the two brothers or even add their third brother into the mix. It is an exciting series, hopefully it does not get overproduce in this franchise if they were to do that.

Some slight info:

Scott suffers from a head injury which inhibits his ability to control the red beams. This coincides closely with the comic book story that the two were in a plane crash (causing the brain injury to Scott).

Alex cannot control his powers either. This is because the beams are random circular wheels that go off in every direction.

The two have a younger brother named Vulcan/Gabriel who is supposedly 10-12 years younger than Alex, but he is matured faster than he should by an incubator machine, after he was stolen from his mothers womb and the two older boys thrown from the plane believing he other had died. Vulcan appears to be older than Alex by 5-6 years.

Comment: This might clear some things up & is also an amusing read: [In Defense of Cyclops](http://grantland.com/hollywood-prospectus/difficult-x-men-a-defense-of-cyclops)

Answer (score 6):

As you can surmise from the age issue, they are not brothers in the film universe.

Bryan Singer confirmed this [in an interview a few years ago](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/MarvelFreshman/news/?a=29870).

> When questioned of Havok & Cyclops' "brother" relation, **“Yes, the time line is different,” Singer said. “It wouldn’t physically fit for him to be the brother of Cyclops.** We take some liberties on that. There are notions, but, um, I don’t want to give away certain interrelations, but let’s just say there are some things that do adhere to the comic books and do so in a way the fans will get a kick out of. And those things can, perhaps, move forward into the future….

Specifically what their relationship *is* has been unconfirmed at this point.

Comment: Thakyou for commenting back:)

Comment: Of course, as of *X-Men: Apocalypse*, Alex Summers *is* now Scott Summers’ brother, but his older brother — and, presumably, about *20 years* older.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda mentioned in the movie *Days Of Futures Past* as the "ripple effect", by using that analogy that time/destiny always goes back to it's natural course despite ripples affecting it, it implies that characters no longer have to be from the same part of the timeline but would have the same mutations etc whenever they were born. If Havok is "freed" by Mystique in 73 then he would easily be the right age to become Cyclops' father if they ignore the "alien connection". Likewise if their father was alien, then his visits might be years apart as time would exist differently elsewhere so there could be 20+ years difference between siblings.

Another character this could affect would be Archangel, who in the canon is an important part of the Apocalypse. In the altered timeline, Warren Worthington could be born in a different time to become a Horseman in the 80's set Apocalypse story to the one who appeared in Last Stand, indeed his family would have a different life once Trask was incarcerated and his father would likely take over the work.

Answer (score 0):

My Grandma was born 1945 and is one of six, my youngest Great Uncle was born in 1967 so my Grandma was 22 when he was born, by this point my Grandma had already given birth to my Uncle in 1966 and my Dad followed in 1969. In Apocalypse(now out) it is confirmed Alex is the older brother of Scott so it is possible to have such an age gap.